# What does the rank function do by default for pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading *Python for Data Analysis* by Wes McKinney and came across the following:

Ranking assigns ranks from one through the number of valid data points in an array. The rank methods for Series and DataFrame are the place to look; by default `rank` breaks ties by assigning each group the mean rank:

```
In [215]: obj = pd.Series([7, -5, 7, 4, 2, 0, 4])

In [216]: obj.rank()
Out[216]:
0   6.5
1   1.0
2   6.5
3   4.5
4   3.0
5   2.0
6   4.5
dtype: float64
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea what this function does, and I find the explanation and the related documentation equally confusing: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rank.html

I can't make heads or tails of this, what is this function doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**

- In general, Ranking creates the numerical values 1 through *n* for the sorted data with *n* values.

In order to understand  `pandas.Series.rank()`, you need to first understand what the ranking is, you can refer to [Ranking-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking) and [Test for Rank data](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-statistics/chapter/tests-for-ranked-data/#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20%E2%80%9Cranking%E2%80%9D%20refers,3%2C%201%20and%204%20respectively.) to understand it clearly.

As rank works on sorted data, try to sort the data first

```
obj.sort_values()
1   -5
5    0
4    2
3    4
6    4
0    7
2    7
```

After sorting the data, each value will have its own rank from 1 to *n*, and as `-5` is the lowest value, its rank is `1`.
`0` is the second lowest value so it will have rank 2, and 2 has rank 3, but 4 is the 4th lowest value, and is repeated.

As per [Series.rank documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html), there is a parameter called `method` which has the default value as `average`, what it does is, it uses the average values as default for the repeated data. It first sorts the data then calculates the rank, and finally maps the input to an output based on the rank value.

Hence, two 4's will have ranks 4 and 5, and their `average` is 4.5, similarly, the two 7's have ranks 6 and 7, and the `average` is 6.5

Answer (score 0):

Update: looking this over, I have figured it out.

-5 is the smallest value in the array, hence the `argmin` index (1) for the element with value -5 has rank==1.0, the next smallest value is 0, hence the index of that value has rank==2.0. Finally, the largest value is 7, but it appears twice, hence it is both the 6th and 7th ranked element, so it's average rank is 6.5